# Closure callbacks in PHP (Laravel 5)

Tags: php, closures, laravel-5

I am learning Laravel 5, and getting a little bit confused at these lines of code (creation of service provider):

```
 public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('Riak\Contracts\Connection', function($app)
    {
        return new Connection($app['config']['riak']);
    });
}
```

I cant understand `$app` variable, and frome where it will be passed into function? Thanks!

P.S. And please correct if I wrong, I read some posts, and how I understand closures is a anonimous functions what uses vars from outside scope (by using `use ()`), and lambda functions is just closure what doesnt use these vars. Or I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `$this->app->singleton` that passes `$app` to the callback closure when it is called.

Answer (score 1):

The anonymous function is a `Callable` which is passed to the function `singleton` in the object `$app`.

The function `singleton` then calls the `Callable` (anonymous function) that you passed to it, and passes `$app` as argument into the anonymous function.